# Cognito user pool implementation on Node Lambda server

Tags: node.js, authentication, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use cognito user pools with my side project but I'm having a hard time finding examples where cognito is used server side.

There is a ton of documentation all over the place that is really throwing me off. I'm using the amazon-cognito-identity-js package, but I'm also finding resources to AWS Amplify that look entirely different from amazon-cognito-identity-js even though that package is ["part of amplify"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/setting-up-the-javascript-sdk.html).

I currently have Signing in, Signing up, and confirming users done and working.

Sign in/Sign Up:

```
var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

var pool = {
    UserPoolId : 'pool-id',
    ClientId : 'client-id'
};
var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(pool);

var cognitoSignUp = (body, attributeList) => new Promise((acc, rej) => {
    userPool.signUp(body.email, body.password, attributeList, null, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
            rej(err);
        } else {
            acc(res);
        }
    });
});

var cognitoSignIn = (body) => new Promise((acc, rej) => {
    var authData = {
        Username: body.email,
        Password: body.password
    }
    var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authData);
    var userData = {
        Username: body.email,
        Pool: userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function(res) {
            acc(res);
        }, 
        onFailure: function(err) {
            rej(err);
        }
    });
});
```

My next step is to make sure I secure my lambda API endpoints. This is where I'm having a very hard time.

Ive been looking through these resources on how to get the current user on the server and validating that the user is authenticated and protecting apis.

- [aws overview on tokens cognito returns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)
- [aws overview on validating tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-step-1)
- [validating token example from 3rd party](https://medium.com/@prasadjay/amazon-cognito-user-pools-in-nodejs-as-fast-as-possible-22d586c5c8ec)
- [validating user based on the session data](https://blog.jsecademy.com/how-to-authenticate-users-with-tokens-using-cognito/)
- [protecting lambda apis with lmabda authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html)
- [protecting lambda apis with a user pool authorizer as an alternative to lambda authorizers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html)

Through this research I've found 2 ways to validate the current user

- verify the tokens manually
- verify the session (taken from 4th link above)

  ```
  const AccessToken = new CognitoAccessToken({ AccessToken: tokens.accessToken });
  const IdToken = new CognitoIdToken({ IdToken: tokens.idToken });
  const RefreshToken = new CognitoRefreshToken({ RefreshToken: tokens.refreshToken });
  const sessionData = {
    IdToken: IdToken,
    AccessToken: AccessToken,
    RefreshToken: RefreshToken
  };
  const userSession = new CognitoUserSession(sessionData);
  const userData = {
    Username: email,
    Pool: this.userPool
  };
  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.setSignInUserSession(userSession);
  cognitoUser.getSession(function (err, session) { // You must run this to verify that session (internally)
    if (session.isValid()) {
      // Update attributes or whatever else you want to do
    } else {
      // TODO: What to do if session is invalid?
    }
  });
  ```

And I've found 2 ways to protect APIs

- Lambda Authorizer
- User pools as authorizer

Now I'm just kind of stuck frozen not knowing what path to take. My biggest gripe with the AWS documentation is that it tells you what you need to do but provides no examples on how to do it. For example the Authorizer stuff I haven't found aws examples on. Also the npm package for the [amazon-cognito-identity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) doesn't even talk about the tokens cognito returns or how to use them, it's just been a client side implementation. All examples I've found on this have been on blogs other users have created.

Does anyone have any guidance, or full complete examples of using cognito user pools with lambda?

Thank you